# SwitchPreferenceCompat summary text being cut off (too long)

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have, inside my xml file:

```
<SwitchPreferenceCompat
  app:key="@string/key"
  app:persistent="false"
  app:summary="@string/very_long_text"
  app:title="@string/title" />
```

Problem is that `app:summary="very_long_text"` is being cut off. It only shows 10 lines and the rest is not shown. How can I fix this?

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for issues/problems with the Android Studio product. This question has nothing to do with the Android Studio product.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution, add app:layout="" and specify a layout that has `android:maxLines="15"`, for example.